# getProductUrl returns wrong string length

Tags: magento

I have 2 websites on the same server (dev and live).

When I dump product's url (`var_dump($_product->getProductUrl())`), results are:

Dev : `string(51) "http://dev.abcd.com/nine-west-cao-got-mau-nude.html"`

Live: `string(60) "http://www.abcd.com/nine-west-cao-got-mau-nude.html"`

As you see, on the live website, **wrong string length returned**, expected 51 (you can check word count) but it returns 60. No blank space, no tab, no break line, even I tried `trim()`, string is correct, but string length is not.

I check other products' url, it always returns 9 more than expected.

**It only occurs on the live website**. What happends behind? **What can cause of this problem?**

It took my days but I cannot figure it out.

Help me some suggestions to test this case.

Comment: Did you dump the product's url correctly? I think there might be index.php ? http://www.abcd.com/index.php/nine-west-cao-got-mau-nude.html

Comment: oh no, sorry, no index.php in url, because I enabled rewrite already.